# VIM: deleting non-roman characters

Tags: vim, internationalization, cjk

I'm working with a document with both Roman and Asian characters, and I want put them each of them alone in two separated files and keeps their original structure, is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: It's encoded with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easier in Python. Here's a script that reads a text file and creates two output files: one with low-ASCII and one with everything else. If you have Python support compiled in Vim, the following should also be usable from within Vim (with minimal changes).

```
import codecs

mixedInput = codecs.open('mixed.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')
lowAsciiOutput = codecs.open('lowAscii.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
otherOutput = codecs.open('other.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')

for rawline in mixedInput:
    line = rawline.rstrip()
    for c in line:
        if ord(c) < 2**7:
            lowAsciiOutput.write(c)
        else:
            otherOutput.write(c)
    otherOutput.write('\n')
    lowAsciiOutput.write('\n')

mixedInput.close()
lowAsciiOutput.close()
otherOutput.close()
```

example input file (mixed.txt):

```
欢迎来到Mifos管理区域
```

Does that do what you want?

Also saved as a gist: https://gist.github.com/855545

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I want!